# Pokemon: How do I switch back & forth from "real world" camera view?

Tags: pokemon-go

I turned the camera off somehow which made it easier to catch, but can't seem to turn it back on

Answer (score 3):

When catching a Pokemon there should be a little switch at the top right called 'AR' (Augmented Reality). If you click that you will switch between the two modes.